# Request to mediamarkt.es always returns 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

So I'm trying to scrape mediamarkt.es with this code:

```js
PORT = 8000;
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios").default;
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

const app = express();

const ax = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  },
});

const tc = () => {
  ax.get("https://www.mediamarkt.es")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.status);
    });
};

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  tc();
});
```

Every time I get 403 error. Tried on chrome with disabled javascript and cleaned cache, so it works and returns 200, but in nodejs code I always get 403. With 403 there is html which says captcha, but I believe I can make same request with nodejs as chrome do. Just can't imagine what I'm missing...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It needs the session cookie that's set when you solve the CAPTCHA.

Comment: If the site has a CAPTCHA, it means they don't allow scraping. Why are you trying to get around this?

Comment: But in a browser with no cookies, no cache and no js, on the first load I dont get the captcha. How could I replicate this action in my request. Or maybe It's not even possible?

Comment: It may be reCAPTCHA, which works automatically without displaying anything.

Comment: the whole point of CAPTCHA is to make it really hard to replicate in code. They don't want you doing this.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm just trying that for educational purpose. So if in my browser there is no working javascript, how they accepts me without any captcha, while my request from code is blocked?

Comment: I'm surprised it works when you have JS disabled in the browser. I don't know how they do it.

Comment: You should ask for an internal API